# Raising multiple errors for different occasions with Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a question regarding raising multiple errors based on different conditions.

```markdown
| COL1   | COL2 |
|--------|------|
| bread  | 1    |
| milk   | 5    |
| pear   | 9    |
```

i want to raise different errors based on each col1 & col2 combinations. Kind of;

```py
if col1 == bread & col2 > 1:
   bread_alert == 'alert_bread'
else:
   blank

if col1 == milk & col2 > 3:
   milk_alert == 'alert_milk'
else:
   blank

if col1 == pear & col2 > 8:
   pear_alert == 'alert_pear'
else:
   blank
```

then append the errors together if any of them occur.

result would be
**milk alert and pear alert**

any ideas on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I have updated your question so it is a little easier to read. When you post a question, consider noting the data structure. Is there a Pandas dataframe? If so, please consider providing a simple dummy data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't quite understand what you want to do. There aren't any "errors" to raise here, just strings. I'm also not sure what you mean by `blank`. Do you mean that nothing should happen in the `else` case? Then you were presumably thinking of `pass` - but a better idea is to *just not write an `else:` block*.

Comment: Anyway, please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. If you need help with general program logic, then you should try to follow a tutorial, get help from an instructor, or possibly use an actual discussion forum such as Reddit or Quora. "any ideas on this?" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) that we can answer in this format; it does not correspond to a *specific problem* and is too open-ended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `bread` and such are identifiers. I don't know what `blank` is supposed to represent. Also, I think you mean to use `=` instead of `==`. Anyways, this seems like a great place to use `match` with a tuple:

```
cols = col1, col2

match cols:
    case (bread, col2):
        if col2 > 1:
            bread_alert = 'alert_bread'
```

... and so on. Combining the alerts would be as simple as appending them to an empty list.

Comment: `cols = df.item, df.price

match cols:
    case (tennis ball, df.price):
        if df.price > 5:
            tennis_ball_price = 'tennis_ball_price_alert'`

can you help me to walk through this ?

Comment: `cols` is a tuple of items. Using `match-case`, you look for certain tuple instances. Here, you're only trying to match cases of `df.item`, while you don't know what `df.price` will be - as such, you can "bind" it arbitrarily. You then check the condition of `df.price` and take the appropriate action. See here for a proper explanation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements.

Comment: i got you point. i copy pasted your code thats i guess what made it a bit complicated while i express myself. what i want is this case will be individual for 5 different items thats why i wrote tennis ball there. i guess that needs to be df.item as well. when that df.item is tennis ball then the price should be > 5 to get an alert but i couldnt make it.